# How to track all Google+ +1 button clicks in one place with trackers other than google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

How to track all Google+ +1 button clicks in one place with trackers other than google analytics if I want Google+ JavaScript to be loaded **asynchronously**?
I found the ways with callbacks for Facebook and Twitter, but can't figure out it for Google+. I want to track it with kissmetrics, but it really does not make any difference which tracker, they all have similar API.

Comment: What is wrong with using Google Analytics?

Comment: Nothing wrong, we just want to track this events in other trackers as well

Comment: Check out [Google Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/tagmanager/). You might find it more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

With the +1 button you can also specify a callback method that will be called once the button is clicked by the user. With this, it shouldn't be too hard to either build your own tracking system or delegate the events to your existing tracker, given that they provide an API for custom events.

You can specify a method using the `callback` parameter of the button - either in the button's HTML tag or in the parameter object of the `gapi.plusone.render()` method (when rendering explicitly). The callback method has to be in the global namespace. You can read more about the callback parameter as well as other parameters of the +1 button in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters).

Comment: I know about that, but 1. this way I have to put callback on each and every +1 button in the system; 2. This API is NOT asynchronous.